# How can I sum up the value of a field in a C# collection

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class ViewEvent {

    public long Elapsed { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }

}
```

In my model I have a collection of instances of these classes:

```
public IList<ViewEvent> Events { get; set; }
```

How can I get the total elapsedTime of all the ViewEvents in my Events collection?

Comment: What is problem in iterating each `ViewEvent` one by one and summing up the `Elapsed` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With LINQ, `Events.Sum(event => event.Elapsed);`.

As pointed out by Habib, be sure to add

```
using System.Linq;
```